# How do you return A Table with inserted information in LINQ TO SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, insert

I want to return a table which  I have edited/added information/inserted data to. Here's my code.

```
    using(DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath)){

        PatientInfo patientInfo = new PatientInfo();

        patientInfo.Phy_ID = physcianID;
        patientInfo.Pat_First_Name = txtFirstName.Text;
        patientInfo.Pat_Middle_Name = txtMiddleName.Text;
        patientInfo.Pat_Last_Name = txtLastName.Text;
        patientInfo.Pat_Gender = cmbGender.Text;
        patientInfo.Pat_Marital_Status = cmbMaritalStatus.Text;
        patientInfo.Pat_Date_Of_Birth = dtpDOB.Value;
        patientInfo.Pat_Home_Add = txtHomeAdd.Text;
        patientInfo.Pat_Home_Num = txtPhone.Text;
        patientInfo.Pat_Work_Add = txtWorkAdd.Text;
        patientInfo.Pat_Work_Num = txtWorkPhone.Text;
        patientInfo.Pat_Prim_Physician = txtPrimPhysician.Text;
        patientInfo.Pat_Ref_Physician = txtRefePhysician.Text;


    }
```

Where I want to return patientInfo? what data type is it? how would I create a method which returns it like that?

Comment: I could be misunderstanding your question, but don't you just want a return statement at the end like - return patientInfo;

Comment: but what will be the methods data type? since I am gonna past that information to another variable

Answer (score 1):

You can just return the patientInfo object directly, it will be of type PatientInfo (exactly like it appears in your code now).

You are not actually using the DB context that you are generating in your code.  I assume you want to insert the new PatientInfo to the DB?  Something like:

```
using(DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath)){

    PatientInfo patientInfo = new PatientInfo();

    patientInfo.Phy_ID = physcianID;
    patientInfo.Pat_First_Name = txtFirstName.Text;
    patientInfo.Pat_Middle_Name = txtMiddleName.Text;
    patientInfo.Pat_Last_Name = txtLastName.Text;
    patientInfo.Pat_Gender = cmbGender.Text;
    patientInfo.Pat_Marital_Status = cmbMaritalStatus.Text;
    patientInfo.Pat_Date_Of_Birth = dtpDOB.Value;
    patientInfo.Pat_Home_Add = txtHomeAdd.Text;
    patientInfo.Pat_Home_Num = txtPhone.Text;
    patientInfo.Pat_Work_Add = txtWorkAdd.Text;
    patientInfo.Pat_Work_Num = txtWorkPhone.Text;
    patientInfo.Pat_Prim_Physician = txtPrimPhysician.Text;
    patientInfo.Pat_Ref_Physician = txtRefePhysician.Text;

    //store to db
    myDb.Patients.AddObject(patientInfo);
    myDb.SaveChanges();

    return patientInfo;
}
```

Be careful, the object internally stores a reference to the DataContext you created/updated it with.  If you use it together with later updates/inserts that you have the same context for all of them or you will get exceptions.

Comment: you can directly do that? what will be the return type of the method?

Comment: PatientInfo.  Signature would be something like public PatientInfo insertPatient(params...);

Comment: but that will be a very long parameter. I added the return patientInfo but there are errors

Comment: What errors?  Could you post the whole method code perhaps for us?

Comment: PatientInfo is just another type like any other. Just so happens that Visual Studio generated the code defining that type, rather than you.

Comment: @just.another.programmer here's the error Error 1 Since 'PatientAdministration.Pat_Demog.addPatientInformation()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PatientAdministration\PatientAdministration\Pat_Demog.cs 111 17 PatientAdministration

Comment: You need to change your method signature to return PatientInfo instead of void.  Right now it's something like public void addPatientInformation(), change it to public PatientInfo addPatientInformation().